# Have Magento admin on subdomain (admin.mystore.com)

Tags: url, magento, admin

I've asked this on the magento forum but had no response so thought I would try here.

I am trying to set up my admin url on a subdomain (admin.mystore.com) but it’s not working.

I changed the Custom Admin URL in the admin area to http://admin.mystore.com/ and I have set up the DNS so that admin.mystore.com points to the root of the site.

But I can’t login. when I go to the admin URL is just redirects to the homepage.

Anyone know how to set this up correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You need to set your default store settings to http://admin.example.com/ and then go into the store website settings, setting the base URL to http://www.example.com/.

You will want to clear your cache settings for good measure.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn’t seem to work.

Doing that will still run the main store view. (which is admin.mystore.com) and just shows the standard store home page.

but I need that to actually go to the admin area (e.g. admin.mystore.com/admin)

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Forgot that detail. The admin will still be on /admin i.e. as you have it `http://admin.example.com/admin`. The way round this is to put a `RedirectMatch ^/$ /admin` in the http.conf or htaccess for the admin URL.

Comment: That means that when I go to admin.mystore.com it will automatically redirect to admin.mystore.com/admin. That's not quite what I want. How can I have it so it doesn't have to add the /admin on the end? Thanks

Comment: `RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ /admin` will redirect straight to `/admin`, you then login and then it will put `/index.php/admin/path/to/config` as per normal. You should still be able to simply type `http://admin.example.com` in your address bar and it log you in, albeit with `http://admin.example.com/admin/` showing up on the login screen. That solves what you want to do, worse things have happened?

Comment: absolutely worst things have happened but that's not what I was trying to achieve. I appreciate your help though

Comment: You are on a hiding to nothing being so particular with your admin url - not as if it is seen by the whole world and it is not as if there is sooo much else to get write in Magento! Good luck to you..!

Comment: Maybe but if a client has demanded it I can't go back to him and tell him that he's on "a hiding to nothing". If it's not possible then so be it, but i've not seen anything that states it can't be done.

Comment: As far as the client is concerned he just has to type `http://admin.example.com/` - if your client is going to have a problem with that then get a new client - proposed solution is job done unless they want to pick a fight with you?

Comment: Ok I understand what you're saying. And I understand that it may seem petty to require the /admin bit of the url to be gone. But thems the breaks. It seems odd to have 'admin' in the url twice. Can "My perfect solution" be done? Or are you just saying that you don't know how to achieve it?

Comment: Anything can be done, however, in practical terms it cannot be done. You want one codebase and not a different index.php. You also don't want to be re-writing controllers, models and all that stuff, or mangling the /etc/local/system.xml (or whatever it is called). What you could do to make it 'better' is rename admin in the /etc/local/system.xml to something else, e.g. 'staff'. Didn't you get the memo about how you are supposed to obfuscate the URL to your admin screen?